# Capture type class in returning type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

In the following example I have to repeat that that `M` is a `Monad` in order to define `bar` which seems unnecessary since I already told this the compiler as I defined `fnc`.

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.Scalaz._

object MyTest {

  // function returning a function accepting a monad as parameter
  def fnc[M[_]: Monad, T](t: T): (M[T] => T) = xs => t

  // this works
  def bar[M[_]: Monad]: (M[Double] => Double) = fnc(1.0)

  // I would like this also to work
  val foo = fnc(1.0)
}
```

How can I make `foo` a function that accepts any `M[T]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala doesn't have polymorphic functions—the input and output types of any function value must be concrete types (you can, however, have polymorphic methods that return functions, and both your `fnc` and `bar` are examples of this). This means that your `foo` definition will only work if you specify a concrete monadic type:

```
val foo: List[Double] => Double = fnc(1.0)
```

[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) uses objects and implicits together to implement polymorphic function values:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object foo extends shapeless.Poly1 {
  implicit def double[M[_]: Monad]: Case.Aux[M[Double], Double] = at(_ => 1.0)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> foo(List(1.0))
res0: Double = 1.0

scala> foo(Option(1.0))
res1: Double = 1.0

scala> foo(1.0: Id[Double])
res2: Double = 1.0
```

But unfortunately due to the limits of the language there are lots of restrictions on how these polymorphic function values can be defined (it would be difficult to make the `1.0` part a parameter, for example), so in general you're probably better off making polymorphic methods work.